# A property about the automorphisms of $\mathbb{D}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to prove the next proposition: if $T$ is a Möbius transformation from $\mathbb{D}$ to $\mathbb{D}$, then
\begin{equation}
\left|\frac{T(z_1) - T(z_2)}{1 - \overline{T(z_1)} T(z_2)}\right| = \left|\frac{z_1 - z_2}{1 - \overline{z_1} z_2}\right|
\end{equation}
for all $z_1 , z_2 \in \mathbb{D}$, and
\begin{equation}
\frac{|T'(z)|}{1 - {|T(z)|}^2} = \frac{1}{1 - {|z|}^2}
\end{equation}
for all $z \in \mathbb{D}$.

I know that given a Möbius transformation from $\mathbb{D}$ to $\mathbb{D}$, so $T \in \operatorname{Aut}({\mathbb{D}})$ and it takes the form of
\begin{equation}
T(z) = \lambda \frac{z - z_0}{1 - \overline{z_0} z}
\end{equation}
for all $z \in \mathbb{D}$, where $z_0 \in \mathbb{D}$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ with $|\lambda| = 1$. I think supposing that $T$ is of this form, the proof would be easier but I don't know how I can follow with the proof. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "a Möbius transformation from $\mathbb{D}$ to $\mathbb{D}$" you seem to mean a Möbius transformation whose restriction to $\mathbb{D}$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb{D}$. In this setting, the result is true. However, if $T$ is just a Möbius transformation such that $T(\mathbb{D}) \subseteq \mathbb{D}$, then the claim is false: take $T(z) = \frac{1}{2}z$.

---

The result follows from the following result:

> **Schwarz-Pick Theorem**: If $f : \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{D}$ is holomorphic. Then for all $z_1, z_2 \in \mathbb{D}$,
>
> $$\left|\frac{f(z_1) - f(z_2)}{1-\overline{f(z_1)}f(z_2)}\right| \leq \left|\frac{z_1 - z_2}{1-\overline{z_1}z_2}\right|$$
>
> and, for all $z \in \mathbb{D}$,
>
> $$\frac{|f'(z)|}{1-|f(z)|^2} \leq \frac{1}{1 - |z|^2}.$$

If $T$ is a Möbius transformation from $\mathbb{D}$ to $\mathbb{D}$, then so is the inverse Möbius transformation $T^{-1}$. Using Schwarz-Pick twice, we see that

$$\left|\frac{z_1 - z_2}{1-\overline{z_1}z_2}\right| = \left|\frac{T^{-1}(T(z_1)) - T^{-1}(T(z_2))}{1-\overline{T^{-1}(T(z_1))}T^{-1}(T(z_2))}\right| \leq \left|\frac{T(z_1) - T(z_2)}{1-\overline{T(z_1)}T(z_2)}\right| \leq \left|\frac{z_1 - z_2}{1-\overline{z_1}z_2}\right|$$

so that all the inequalities must be equalities. In particular,

$$\left|\frac{T(z_1) - T(z_2)}{1-\overline{T(z_1)}T(z_2)}\right| = \left|\frac{z_1 - z_2}{1-\overline{z_1}z_2}\right|.$$

The proof of the other equality is similar.